# how to define preset height and width of object for constraint (Swift4)

Tags: ios, swift4, nslayoutconstraint, preset

My code creates constraints for uitextfields all programatically. And it works. I am trying to optimize my coding practice and try to find a way to use a preset constraint to determine all of the textfields height and width. As you can see both a1. and a2. are the exact same height and width. I wanted to see if there was a way to just call the same height and width for each textfield and stead of just always coding it.

```
 a1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingc2 = a1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75)
    let trailingC2 = a1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    let topc2 = a1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: -60)
    let bottomc2 = a1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -275)

    a1t = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(a1t)

    //

    a2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingc22 = a2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75)
    let trailingC22 = a2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    let topc22 = a2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 60)
    let bottomc22 = a2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -275)

    a2t = [leadingc22,trailingC22,topc22,bottomc22]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(a2t)
```

Comment: You can constraint one field's dimensions to be equal to the other's: `a2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: a1.widthAnchor).isActive = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //Make a variable?

   let height = 75


 //Or you can make a function to shorten the progress
   func setHeight (object : AnyObject?){
   object.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant : 75).isActive =      true
  }

  //Then do
     setHeight(object : label1)

 // you can expand the function for height and other things (: or change it to set all of them programmatically really quick
```